# Replace underscore with brackets using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string `AverageLogon_Seconds_`

I need to replace the first underscore with `'('` and second Underscore with `')'`.

Means I need to get the text like `AverageLogon(Seconds)`.

I have checked with `str.replace(/_/g, ')');` , but it will replace both the underscore iwth ')'.

Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: A loop based method would be to use a loop and work on the string but not efficient maybe.

Comment: Remove the global flag `g` and repeat. `str.replace(/_/, '(').replace(/_/,')')`

Comment: Will you be getting **only** two brackets in all your string occurences?

Comment: @DavidR Not sure I need t replace the _ with brackets simultaneously

Comment: @tewathia, please add that as an answer.. so that I can mark it as accepted. It works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it with **[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** with a callback and a counter variable. Replace `_` with `(` in an odd position and `)` in an even position where the counter variable can be used for finding out the position.

```js
var str = 'AverageLogon_Seconds_',
  i = 0;

var res = str.replace(/_/g, function() {
  return i++ % 2 == 0 ? '(' : ')';
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks pranav... But I think `str.replace(/_/, '(').replace(/_/,')')` this one is more perfect

Comment: @Manu : it will only work if there if there is only 2 `_` in string .... if more than 2 are there which only replace the first two.... otherwise which is perfect and simple :)

Answer (score 3):

I feel like it would be more prudent to target the `"_something_"` pattern as a whole. Something like

```
str.replace(/_([a-z0-9 -]+)_/gi, '($1)')
```

You can narrow that `[a-z0-9 -]` character class down based on the characters you expect to appear between the underscores. For now, I've got letters, numbers, spaces and hyphens.

---

```js
var tests = [
  'AverageLogon_Seconds_',
  'AverageLogon_Seconds_ and some other_data_',
  'Oh no, too_many_underscores___'],
    out = document.getElementById('out'),
    rx = /_([a-z0-9 -]+)_/gi;

tests.forEach(function(test) {
  out.innerHTML += test + ' => ' + test.replace(rx, '($1)') + '\n';
});
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = 'AverageLogon_Seconds_', replacement = ')';

//replace the last occurence  of '_' with ')'
str = str.replace(/_([^_]*)$/,replacement+'$1');

//replace the remaining '_' with '('
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats easy. Just a one liner needed.

```
testString = "AverageLogon_Seconds_";

replacedString = testString.replace(/_/, '(').replace(/_/, ')');

console.log(replacedString);
```

Output : "AverageLogon(Seconds)"

Comment: Keep in mind, that this only works for input with no more then two underscores. This answers the immediate question, but is not generally applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Pranav's solution is nice. I tend to like to write things that I can very quickly reason about (i.e. sometimes less elegant). Another way (read in DJ Khaled's voice):

```js
function replaceUnderscores(str) {
  return str.split('_').map(function (part, ind) {
    if (part === '') {
      return '';
    }
    if (ind % 2 === 0) {
      return part + '(';
    } else {
      return part + ')';
    }
  }).join('');
}

// "AverageLogon(Seconds)"
console.log(replaceUnderscores('AverageLogon_Seconds_'));
```

Comment: They don't want you to answer questions on SO

Answer (score -2):

will this work

```
var t = "AverageLogon_Seconds_";
var ctr=0;
while(t.contains('_')){
  if(ctr==0){
    t= t.replace('_','(');
    ctr++;
  }
  else{
    t= t.replace('_',')');
    ctr--;
  }
}
```